# How to download a file with React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I am building an app with React Native, for Android and iOS. I am trying to let the user download a PDF file when clicking on a button.

- [react-native-file-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-download) does not support Android
- [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) does nothing when I trigger downloadFile (nothing shows up on the notification bar), and I am not able to find the file after that. I added `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to the Android Manifest file. I double-checked that the file I am trying to download exists (when it does not, the library throws an error)

I do not find other solutions for this problem. I have found libraries for viewing a PDF, but I would like to let the user download the PDF.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Run `npm install rn-fetch-blob`.
2. Follow the installation instructions. If you want to manually install the package without using rnpm, go to their [wiki](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package#index).
3. Finally, that's how I made it possible to download files within my app:

```js
    const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob
    let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir // this is the pictures directory. You can check the available directories in the wiki.
    let options = {
      fileCache: true,
      addAndroidDownloads : {
        useDownloadManager : true, // setting it to true will use the device's native download manager and will be shown in the notification bar.
        notification : false,
        path:  PictureDir + "/me_"+Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2), // this is the path where your downloaded file will live in
        description : 'Downloading image.'
      }
    }
    config(options).fetch('GET', "http://www.example.com/example.pdf").then((res) => {
      // do some magic here
    })
```

Comment: No address associated with hostname getting this error how to resolve it

Comment: *addAndroidDownloads* It's just download for Android, what about iOS?

Comment: react-native-fetch-blob is deprecated use rn-fetch-blob instead

Comment: @Ray I believe this is a workout for android. How about if we want the same to work on ios? I am trying to download an Image from url and display in the device, can you help me out?

Comment: @Ray I am unable to download pdf files on http domain (eg. `http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf`) in MI A1 with Android 9 (Pie) version. Though, I am able to download https domain pdf files (eg. `https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file-sample_150kB.pdf`) on the same device. Please, help me out for http ones.
I have also referred to https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/351 and posted [here](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/issues/677) but still no luck.

Comment: I have 'POST' request type to download file how can I download ?
please suggest

Comment: Hi, i'm using this approach but I can't download files that are bigger than 2MB, any sugestions? With postman I can download normally. I have a code 16 error on my console. Thanks

Answer (score 28):

If you're using Expo, [`react-native-fetch-blob`](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) won't work. Use `FileSystem`.

Here's a working example:

```
const { uri: localUri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(remoteUri, FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'name.ext');
```

Now you have `localUri` with the path to the downloaded file. Feel free to set your own filename instead of `name.ext`.

Comment: My server asks for an Authorization OAuth token in order to allow the download. Is there a way to attach a header??

Comment: @EnriqueDev I don't think so, but you can work around this - just put your token into a GET parameter, and adjust your server to handle it this way

Comment: Yes, I know. But then how can I save the result data into the phone filesystem?

Comment: @EnriqueDev The line of code above actually does save the file into `FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'name.ext'` file.

Comment: @FancyJohn Download icon is not visible on status bar

Comment: Nice, file is downloaded. How do let users choose the path to store it?

Comment: i have arryofbuffer so how can i download it using expo filesystem?

Comment: How to download file using 'POST' method nothing is working for me please suggest

Comment: can u help me plz.... i use expo-file-dl and i get this error: Missing MEDIA_LIBRARY permissions. i check the permissions and app.json file... but I couldn't solve it

Answer (score 6):

I Followed the solution from Jonathan Simonney, above on this post. But I had to change it a little:

```
const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
  const date = new Date();

  const { DownloadDir } = fs.dirs; // You can check the available directories in the wiki.
  const options = {
    fileCache: true,
    addAndroidDownloads: {
      useDownloadManager: true, // true will use native manager and be shown on notification bar.
      notification: true,
      path: `${DownloadDir}/me_${Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2)}.pdf`,
      description: 'Downloading.',
    },
  };

  config(options).fetch('GET', 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf').then((res) => {
    console.log('do some magic in here');
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  GetItem_downloadbtn = (item, itemname) => {
    console.log("fiel url comiugn jdd   " + item);
    console.log("item name checkoing " + itemname);
    const android = RNFetchBlob.android;
    const filename = itemname;
    const filepath = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir + '/foldernamae/' + filename;
    const downloadAppUrl = item;

    RNFetchBlob.config({
        addAndroidDownloads: {
            useDownloadManager: true,
            title: 'great, download success',
            description:'an apk that will be download',
            mime: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive',
            // mime: 'image/jpeg',
            // mediaScannable: true,
            notification: true,
            path: filepath
        }
    })
    .fetch('GET', downloadAppUrl)
    .then((res) => {
        // console.log('res.path ', res.path());
        alert('res.path ', res.path());
        android.actionViewIntent(res.path(), 'application/vnd.android.package-archive');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        alert('download error, err is', JSON.stringify(err));
    });
  }
```

Comment: 100% working Please follow guys.

Comment: RNFetchBlob does NOT work with expo...

Comment: Hi, My API generates pdf content in response and Most important it is POST api not GET. PDF generated but shows invalid format

Comment: great thanks bro! 100% works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, got it working using Expo WebBrowser Module

```
// install module 
npm install react-native-webview

// import the module
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

// then in your function you can call this function
await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(file_ur);
```

it will open preview of the file and then user can download using share button.

Comment: You're installing `react-native-webview` & importing from `expo-web-browser`, how is that possible?