# React-native, Continue downloading process in background

Tags: android, react-native, service, android-asynctask, background

I'm trying to download video with react-native, but it spend much time then I want to continue processing from foreground to background.

Example:
User click Download Video => Downloading => About 30%, 50% or etc.. of processing, user want to use another app => switch app and video keep downloading

Any solution for this?
I need solution for android first

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't find module in `react-native`, you should probably make Android module for it.. (Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546891/6948643) ?)

And you can start searching like `"android url download using service"`,
and then make [Native module](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html).