# How to download a pdf file in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I am building an app with React Native and Expo, for Android and iOS. I am trying to let the user download a PDF file when clicking on a button.
It's a couple of days that I'm working on it and I find tow following packages:

1. react-native-fetch-blob/rn-fetch-blob
2. react-native-fs

the first one raises :
 
**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNFetchBlob.DocumentDir')** 
and for second the error is:
**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')** 
I've previously tested the npm link , Yarn eject , restart packager and some other workarounds form GitHub and stackoverFlow but my problem is not solved yet.

any help is highly appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm currently trying to use rn-fetch-blob to to precisely the same thing.

Comment: Hi friend. I recently abandoned this project and started another project, but I will start it again soon. and if I find the solution I will write it here.

Comment: I managed to sort-of getting it to work on Android using rn-fetch-blob, but not iOS yet..

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546199/how-to-download-a-file-with-react-native