# Download file from url in react-native

Tags: javascript, postman, react-native

I'm trying to download an mp3 file from a given URL, URL format is
`https://aaaa.net/?cmd=OG-translate&user=xxx&device_id=xxxx&input_text=Fine&lang=fr&output_file=151.20200706103512.mp3&info=tts_mp3`

I want to download the file specified by output_file parameter `151.20200706103512.mp3` and save it. I've seen few examples, where file download URL is of format `http://www.example.com/example.pdf`, using `RNFetchBlob`. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546199/how-to-download-a-file-with-react-native).

I've also tried using fetch

```js
fetch("https://aaaa.net/?cmd=OG-translate&user=xxx&device_id=xxxx&input_text=Fine&lang=fr&output_file=151.20200706103512.mp3&info=tts_mp3", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

But I get the blob data.
[image]

In postman, I can save the file using `send and download` button with a `GET` request. How can I download this file in react-native app? So maybe I've to save this raw format in `.mp3` file?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44546199/how-to-download-a-file-with-react-native?

Comment: Here is an answer that should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/44546891/9204320